# perl - conditional array declarations

Tags: arrays, perl, conditional-statements

Perl question for you all.  I have the following code:

```
#! /usr/local/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Switch;

our @ITEMS_ARRAY = qw ( a b c );

foreach my $i (0 .. $#ITEMS_ARRAY) {
  switch ($ITEMS_ARRAY[$i]) {
    case "a" { print "a\n" }
    case "b" { print "b\n" }
    case "c" { print "c\n" }
  }
}
```

which works fine.  I need to set up "@ITEMS_ARRAY" differently for certain cases.  Like the following:

```
#! /usr/local/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Switch;

our $X = 1;

if ($X) {
  our @ITEMS_ARRAY = qw ( a b c );
} else {
  our @ITEMS_ARRAY = qw ( e f g );
}

foreach my $i (0 .. $#ITEMS_ARRAY) {
  switch ($ITEMS_ARRAY[$i]) {
    case "a" { print "a\n" }
    case "b" { print "b\n" }
    case "c" { print "c\n" }
    case "e" { print "e\n" }
    case "f" { print "f\n" }
    case "g" { print "g\n" }
  }
}
```

But, I get the following errors:

```
Variable "@ITEMS_ARRAY" is not imported at ./r.pl line 14.
Variable "@ITEMS_ARRAY" is not imported at ./r.pl line 15.
Global symbol "@ITEMS_ARRAY" requires explicit package name at ./r.pl line 14.
Global symbol "@ITEMS_ARRAY" requires explicit package name at ./r.pl line 15.
Execution of ./r2.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: 1) Don't `use Switch`, ever.  2) Declare `@ITEMS_ARRAY` outside of the block.

Comment: Thanks much, appreciate the help!

Comment: @user5150183: As the documentation for `Switch` says, ***do not use if you can use given/when***. `given` and `when` were introduced in version v5.10 of Perl together with smart matching, but you shouldn't use them either as they're *experimental* features, and you would frustrate people if you asked for help with code that uses them as everybody else is avoiding them and they would have to read the documentation to help you

Comment: Note: There's almost no reason to ever use `our`, except for `our @ISA` and `our @EXPORT_OK`. Use `my`

Comment: Switch is very experimental module, that uses slow and potentially buggy mechanism of source filters (perl source code parsing/interpreting inside of the "main" compiled perl code - like eval "string"), so you must use given/when, or, better, hash containing link to anonymous subroutines - whenever possible. It is strongly not recommended to use Switch module in any production environment.

Comment: Thanks all!  I modified my code to given/when.  :)

Answer (score 1):

`our` is block-scoped. You need to declare outside of the block so that the variable is visible in the outer scope.

```
our $X = 1;
our @ITEMS_ARRAY;

if ($X) {
  @ITEMS_ARRAY = qw ( a b c );
} else {
  @ITEMS_ARRAY = qw ( e f g );
}
```

Comment: Thanks much, got it!  :)